# Index seek changes to index scan on change of value in where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `ORDER` having 64 columns, `OrderNo` being the Primary Key. It has two more columns `ParentOrderNo` and `Type`. For lone orders, Type and `ParentOrderNo` will be NULL and for grouped orders, `Type` will have either 'PRNT' or 'CHLD' populated. The OrderNo `where Type='PRNT'`, will be populated to the `ParentOrderNo` column for all orders in its group(both PRNT and CHLD). One group can have 1 parent and 2 or more child orders. The table has a Non-Clustered index (IX_ORDER_1) for columns `ParentOrderNo` and `Type`.

There are total 31654 rows in this table. In my test case there are 30001 orders(1 parent and 30000 children).

When I execute query:

```
Select top 1 *
  From   ORDER                  
  where PARENTORDERNO = '11278'  and Type ='prnt'
```

execution plan shows Index Seek using (IX_ORDER_1)

but when I execute query:

```
Select top 1 *
  From   ORDER                  
  where PARENTORDERNO = '11278'  and Type ='chld'
```

execution plan shows Index Scan using clustered index

Can someone guide me what is causing this change in execution plan.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the statistics that the database maintains about the indexes, the optimizer (correctly) estimated that there are very few records matching the criteria when `type='parent'`, so a seek is more efficient. For `type='child'`, it estimated that there are enough records that a scan will be more efficient as it will be returning most of what's on the table, instead of only one record.

In the Execution Plan, look at the `Estimated Rows` (and `Actual Rows`, to see how accurate the estimate is) for the two different runs.

Comment: When does a scan become more efficient than a seek? and how?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I cannot add comment, so I answer this way:

When do you SELECTing more that cca 15% rows (percentages varies over sources, but usually they stick to 10 to 15%) from your table, there is high probability that Execution Plan will use Index Scan instead of index Seek.

In your case, if I understand correctly, you have

" In my test case there are 30001 orders(1 parent and 30000 children). "

only one Parent row, which is good candidate to index seek, and 30 000 children rows, which is, for Query optimizer definitely bad candidate.

Comment: Your answer is very useful. I clicked on 'This answer is useful' button. But I got this message "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score". Thanks for help.
My reputation is 6 at the moment. :(